# Does a webserver need to have outgoing port 80 blocked for security reasons?

Tags: windows, security, webserver, ports

At work, we've got Windows Server 2008 running. I've set up XAMPP, and a few websites - everything works perfectly.

However, outgoing port 80 is blocked in the firewall for 'security' reasons. I was wondering if there's any merit to this?

Comment: The firewall in the server? Or the firewall in a spearate box that shields your company's network from the internet?

Comment: Sounds like typical behavior from Windows. Block outgoing HTTP, IT'S DANGEROUS!! (end sarcasm)

Comment: Tim, after you have had your corporate machines turned into a 'bot network and had to deal with the consequences you'll learn the value of egress filtering and not say anything that daft again.

Answer (score 2):

Well, from a security standpoint, every port should be closed by default. And then if there is need,the necessary port can be opened. Port 80 isn't or shouldn't be an exception.